# Filtering Dates based on DateRangeSelector user input using datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I have the following lines of code that you can display quickly using https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new. Make sure to select the dependency "react-datepicker" from the down left corner:

**What I have:**

1 check box, and 2 date input boxes for users to select a specific date range.

**What I want:**

I have an array of dates ("my_date_array"), and I want a code to filter the dates based on the following conditions:

If the checkbox is selected, display all data.
If the checkbox is not selected, display only the data that is within the (inclusive) range of the user-selected start and end date.

The format does not matter I want to display filtered my_date_array based on the conditions on the screen below the input boxes.

One important note is that I want to be able to take the filtered date array outside the function and still be able to use it.

Here is what I have, Thank you for your time!

```
import React from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";




class DateRangeSelector extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showAll: true, // Set showAll to true by default
      startDate: null,
      endDate: null
    };

    this.handleCheckboxChange = this.handleCheckboxChange.bind(this);
    this.handleStartDateChange = this.handleStartDateChange.bind(this);
    this.handleEndDateChange = this.handleEndDateChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleCheckboxChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      showAll: event.target.checked
    });
  }

  handleStartDateChange(date) {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  }

  handleEndDateChange(date) {
    this.setState({
      endDate: date
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.state.showAll}
            onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}
          />
          Show all times
        </label>


        <br />
        <label>
          Start date:
          <DatePicker
            selected={this.state.startDate}
            onChange={this.handleStartDateChange}
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          End date:
          <DatePicker
            selected={this.state.endDate}
            onChange={this.handleEndDateChange}
          />
        </label>
      </form>
    );
  }
}




const my_date_array =["12/07/2022", "11/30/2022","09/08/2022","04/07/2020", "11/04/1994"]

// Use the returned value to display a message to the user
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
    <DateRangeSelector />

  </div>
    
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: are you searching for excludeDates?. 
https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-date-range-for-one-datepicker-with-disabled-dates-highlighted

Comment: Hello, no I am looking for the specific condition I asked under "What I want". I have an array of dates, I want the interface to filter those dates based on user input. Feel free to let me know if it is unclear.